# Iterating recursively over joined items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check the joined contents of a list against the keys of a dictionary of valid outputs. I want to favour the longest, rightmost matches first. As a visual aid, the order the keys are entered into the dictionary is the order I want the output to prefer.

I feel like I'm about halfway to a solution but I've been messing with the code for so long my brain is just going in circles.

Edit: septra provided the following code, which does 90% of what I want it to do

```
foo = ['1','2','3']
bar = ['1','2','2','3']
foobar = ['dog','horse']
foodbar = ['2','3','1']
valid_list = {'1 2 3':'1 2 3','2 3':'2 3','1 2':'1 2','3':'3','2':'2','1':'1'}
def validCheck(check, valid_list):
    for r in range(len(check)):
        key = " ".join(check[r:])
        if key in valid_list:
            return valid_list[key]
print(validCheck(foo, valid_list))
print(validCheck(bar, valid_list))
print(validCheck(foobar, valid_list))
print(validCheck(foodbar, valid_list))
```

which prints

```
'1 2 3'
'2 3'
'None'
'1'
```

as opposed to

```
'1 2 3'
'2 3'
'None'
'2 3'
```

And as said in a later comment, ideally it would catch multiple non-overlapping valid inputs with the same criteria as well, but I'm prepared to push that functionality off for now. In that case,

```
validCheck(['2','3','1','2'], valid_list)
```

would print

```
['1 2','2 3']
```

favouring single longer outputs over multiple shorter ones.

Comment: Can you clarify what the function is doing? If it's just a check, shouldn't it return True or False? If it's not a check, what are the desired outputs? Should it return short matches that are not covered by long ones?

Comment: It should return a string of the best match. Here's the simplest way I can put it: If I have a list (or string, not important) 1 2 3 4, I want it to check 1 2 3 4 > 2 3 4 > 1 2 3 > 3 4 > 2 3 > 1 2 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 in that order and return the first match.

Comment: Okay, and if more than one match of the same length is found, you want them in the original order (12, 23)? Or do you want them in the order checked (34,23,12)?

Comment: In the order checked for. If it's possible to easily return a second, non-overlapping match as well, that would be ideal, but I'm prepared to push that functionality back for now and figure something out on my own for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the function you're looking for?

```
def validCheck(check, valid_list):
    all_keys = []
    for r in range(len(check)):
        key = " ".join(check[r:])
        revkey = " ".join(check[-r:-1])

        valid_key = []
        valid_revkey = []

        if key in valid_list:
            valid_key.append(key)
        if revkey in valid_list:
            valid_revkey.append(revkey)

        all_keys.extend(valid_key + valid_revkey)

    return max(all_keys, key=len) if all_keys else None
```

This should take care of the Longest > Right Most requirement.

Comment: I mean, it sure gives the right answer! I'll have to look it over and make sure it'll catch all the usage cases I'll need it to, but it looks right so far. And way simpler! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Okay, it seems like the only problem is that it values the rightmost valid answer over the longest one. Which is way closer than I was, but still not quite right. For example, ['2','3','1'] prints '1' instead of '2 3'.

Comment: Is that the only edge case?

Comment: I think so? As far as valid outputs go, the order of desired output is 'Longest > Rightmost of equal length'. ['2','3','1'] prints '2 3', ['1','2','3'] prints '3', ['2','3','1','2'] prints '1 2'. I hope that illustrates it clearly!

Comment: Ideally it would catch multiple non-overlapping valid inputs with the same criteria as well, but I'm prepared to push that functionality off for now. In that case, ['2','3','1','2'] would print ['1 2','2 3'], favouring single longer outputs over multiple shorter ones.

Comment: Updated the code to take care of the Longest preferred requirement.

Comment: Works great! Sorry someone apparently downvoted you. I can't imagine why. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104048/discussion-between-aryst0krat-and-septra).